# Auto Logout From My Account Custom Tab

Tags: magento2, logout

We are having issue related to auto logout after clicking on custom tab in my account.
Wu upgraded magneto from 2.3.2 to 2.4.3 .

Any suggestions or help please , I can share module code if any one want to check.

Controller :

/**

- Workout. Custom, Streaming Library and Video Playlist
- 
- @author    Bigdrop inc.
- @category  Bigdrop
- @package   Bigdrop_Workout
- @license   http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
  */
  namespace Bigdrop\Workout\Controller;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

abstract class AbstractCustomer extends AbstractAccount
{
/**
* @var Session
*/
protected $customerSession;

```
/**
 * Index constructor.
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Session $customerSession
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $customerSession
) {
    
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}

/**
 * @return Customer
 */

protected function _getCustomer()
{

    return $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
}
```

}
?>

Helper:

```
<?php
```

/**

- Workout. Custom, Streaming Library and Video Playlist
- 
- @author   Bigdrop inc.
- @category Bigdrop
- @package  Bigdrop_Workout
- @license  http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
  */
  namespace Bigdrop\Workout\Helper;

use Bigdrop\Subscription\Helper\Subscription;
use Bigdrop\Workout\Api\ChallengeRepositoryInterface;
use Bigdrop\Workout\Api\Data\ChallengeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\AddressRegistry;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone;
use Bigdrop\Workout\Api\VideosRepositoryInterface;

class Challenge extends Data
{
const CUSTOMER_CHALLENGE_ATTR_CODE = 'challenge';

```
/**
 * @var ChallengeRepositoryInterface
 */
private $challengeRepository;
/**
 * @var VideosRepositoryInterface
 */
private $videosRepository;
/**
 * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
 */
private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

/**
 * Challenge constructor.
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Session $customerSession
 * @param ResourceConnection $resource
 * @param Timezone $localeDate
 * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
 * @param AddressRegistry $addressRegistry
 * @param Subscription $subscriptionHelper
 * @param ChallengeRepositoryInterface $challengeRepository
 * @param VideosRepositoryInterface $videosRepository
 * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $customerSession,
    ResourceConnection $resource,
    Timezone $localeDate,
    CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    AddressRegistry $addressRegistry,
    Subscription $subscriptionHelper,
    ChallengeRepositoryInterface $challengeRepository,
    VideosRepositoryInterface $videosRepository,
    SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
) {

    $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
    $logger = new \Zend_Log();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('__construct Helper/Challenge.php');
    
    parent::__construct($context, $customerSession, $resource, $localeDate, $customerRepository, $addressRegistry, $subscriptionHelper);
    $this->challengeRepository = $challengeRepository;
    $this->videosRepository = $videosRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
}

/**
 * @param CustomerInterface $customer
 * @param $challengeId
 * @return $this
 */
public function saveCustomerChallenge($customer, $challengeId)
{   

    $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
    $logger = new \Zend_Log();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('saveCustomerChallenge Helper/Challenge.php');

    if (!$this->subscriptionHelper->isCustomerSubscribedOnCW($customer) || !$challengeId) {
        return $this;
    }

    $customer->setCustomAttribute(
        self::CUSTOMER_CHALLENGE_ATTR_CODE,
        $challengeId
    );

    try {
        $this->disableAddressValidation($customer);
        $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
    } catch (LocalizedException $exception) {
        $this->_logger->error('Saving Customer Challenge - '.$exception->getMessage());
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param CustomerInterface $customer
 * @return array
 */
public function getCustomerChallenge($customer)
{
     $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
    $logger = new \Zend_Log();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('getCustomerChallenge Helper/Challenge.php');

    $result = [];

    if (!$this->subscriptionHelper->isCustomerSubscribedOnCW($customer)) {
        return $result;
    }

    $attribute = $customer->getCustomAttribute(self::CUSTOMER_CHALLENGE_ATTR_CODE);

 

    if (!$attribute || !$attribute->getValue()) {
        return $result;
    }

    try {
        /** @var \Bigdrop\Workout\Model\Challenge $challenge */
        $challenge = $this->challengeRepository->getById($attribute->getValue());
        $result = $challenge->getData();
    } catch (LocalizedException $exception) {
        $this->_logger->error('Error while retrieving Customer Challenge - '.$exception->getMessage());
    }
       $logger->info(print_r($result));
    return $result;
}

/**
 * @param ChallengeInterface $challenge
 * @return array|ProductInterface[]
 */
public function fetchVideosCollection(ChallengeInterface $challenge)
{
    $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
    $logger = new \Zend_Log();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('fetchVideosCollection Helper/Challenge.php');
    
    $videosCollection = $challenge->getAssociatedVideos();

    if (!$videosCollection->getSize()) {
        return [];
    }

    return $videosCollection->getItems();
}
```

}

Comment: Is the user automatically log out when they click on the custom tab? It could be a PHP error that kills the cookie or custom code that logs the user out. Could you provide a little more info?

Comment: Yes they logged out automatically when they click on custom tab. In log we are not getting any error related to this. In module we are using GraphQl and customer session etc.

Let me know if you need more info or code files.

Comment: It's possible your custom logic is overload session size and it's a reason why customer logout. Make sense to update question with some additional information about logic in your custom controller. Try to increase PHP session size for frontend first https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/353147/can-we-increase-the-system-security-session-size-at-admin-on-magento-2.

Comment: Not fixed by increasing session  size.

Comment: Our controller:-
namespace Bigdrop\Workout\Controller;
use Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
abstract class AbstractCustomer extends AbstractAccount
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
    protected function _getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
    }
}